# Rancher error when setting a boolean field with an environment variable

Tags: yaml, unmarshalling, rancher

I have a rancher-compose.yml file where I set the upgrade_strategy.start_first field using an environment variable like this:

```
  upgrade_strategy:
    start_first: ${START_FIRST}
    batch_size: 1
```

When running using the rancher-compose CLI, I get the following error:

```
ERRO[0000] Failed to open project origami-svcproxy: yaml: unmarshal errors:
  line 28: cannot unmarshal !!str `false` into bool
```

When running in debug I see the following yaml:

```
  upgrade_strategy:
    batch_size: 1
    start_first: "false"  # <-- notice the surrounding quotes, missing from the rest of the variable replacements
```

How can I set this field dynamically?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and used a different strategy to fix the issue. First step is to convert `docker-compose.yml` to a template, `docker-compose.yml.tpl`. Second, use template logic to fetch the value of the boolean variable.

```
  upgrade_strategy:
    start_first: {{ .Values.START_FIRST }}
    batch_size: 1
```

Reference: https://github.com/rancher/rancher-catalog/blob/v1.6-development/infra-templates/ipsec/9/docker-compose.yml.tpl#L21

Comment: Similar to my solution - since the rancher-compose ran from a makefile, I've created a template and then replaced the relevant values using sed